# Change size of container of animated view

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, view, android-animation

[image: Scenario]

I'm animating a view using `TranslateAnimation` in order to achieve a drop down view animation. The problem I'm facing is that size of the container does not increase after the animation has finished.

Please check the image and snippet code:

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, top, top + px);
animation.initialize(mDropDownLayout.getWidth(),mDropDownLayout.getHeight(), parentLayout.getWidth(), parentLayout.getHeight());
animation.setDuration(2000);
animation.setFillEnabled(true);
animation.setFillBefore(true);
mDropDownLayout.startAnimation(animation);
```

The result I'm trying to achieve is that the container's height should increase as the as the animated view is translating, progressively.

**UPDATE:** Also, the animated view is moved only visually, not structurally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got this. Android has two types of animation packages, **View animation**(android.view.animation) and **Property animation**(android.animation). The latter one was introduced with Honeycomb.

I tried animating first with view animation but in vain, because I was not able to move the layout structure to the visual position after the animation was completed.

Then, I tried it with the Property Animation and I was able to achieve the desired results. 
I highly recommend using property animation and you can also use it for api levels below 11 by using [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) library.

I've added the demo project on github. [Check it here](https://github.com/a001u/Animation-Demo.git)

**NOTE :** You will need NineOldAndroids library in order to run this demo on all api levels.

Comment: The demo seems to be removed. Do you have any other link for the source code.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this way but try once.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

set this layoutParams to your `relativeLayout`

then you can change width/height based on your requirement like below

```
layoutParams.width = 10;
layoutParams.height = 10;
```

Comment: I tried that, but the problem with doing it this way is that it gives an abrupt increase in the height of the container first and then the animation is performed. so, if this container is used in a listview, the item below this container will go down first and then the animation will be performed. This would not help in creating a polished app.

Comment: I think it wl cm smooth if u can handle animation progress or else as u r giving time for animation, u can run a timer equals to that animation time and after specified time elapses, increase/decrease size of layout

Comment: I cannot use a timer for what you said because, the animated view will not be seen entirely, during animation(since container height increases after the timer goes off) . The other thing is that, how do I increase the container height while the animation is progressing? Which methods to use or override?

Comment: regarding animation progress, I am not aware of any method r way. Using timer in the sense, as your view takes 2 seconds to drop down, I thought u can manually enlarge layout in that 2 second time periodically.

Comment: I tried using the timer. The animation works, only visually. However, when I check the hierarchyviewer,  the animated view does not change its position. The animated view remains where it was previously, that is, the position where it was before the animation. So, If I want to close the drop down, I've to click where the animated view was previously.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help Braj. I figured it out. I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Layout Transitions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55wLsaWpQ4g) are ideal, as indicated in this DevBytes episode